# Using C++ to import registry files

Tags: c++, c, windows, registry

I'm having some problems of getting the following simple code to run correctly:

```
#include <process.h>

int main( void )
{
  system("foo.reg");               //why does this NOT WORK?!
  //system("reg import foo.reg");  //why does this NOT WORK?!
  //system("regedit \"foo.reg\""); //why does this NOT WORK?!
  return 0;
}
```

The registry file is located in the directory where the compiled executable is. *foo.reg* runs successfully when I run it from command line, but running the above program only shows the regedit confirmation window, and does no corresponding change in the registry itself.

I used Dev-C++ to write the program and I am running Windows XP x64 version SP2. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it maybe changing the 32 bit registry rather than the 64 bit registry?

Comment: The second two lines don't work because they are commented out.

Comment: @bta: I guess he knows it already :)

Answer (score 3):

`system("regedit /s foo.reg");` should import it silently without any confirmation dialogs. [Refer here](http://techsupt.winbatch.com/ts/T000001029F18.html) for command-line options of *regedit.exe*. However, I will be sceptical about the registry file (foo.reg) in question; check if it's correct. Also after running it, be sure if you're checking the right path in the registry which `foo.reg` is made to amend.

On a side note, `system()` function of the C Standard Library is declared in `stdlib.h` so it should be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    system("regedit /s foo.reg");
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

I think the import is already successful; since you've mentioned that it's a 64-bit XP machine, I think the change will be lying under the `Wow6432Node`. E.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`. So check under the `Wow6432Node` too. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869783/windows-64-bit-registry-v-s-32-bit-registry) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724072%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more information on this.

Comment: system("regedit /s foo.reg") was silent, but it didn't change anything in the registry, with the included "<stdlib.h>" added, too.
And the registry file is correct; if I double click the file itself,  it will prompt me to confirm, but after so it does update the registry.

Comment: I looked up the Wow6432Node folder, but it didn't contain the registry files I'm updating...
Could it be that in order to change registry files, I need to use other functions than system()?

Comment: FYI, I am trying to edit information under
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Comment: @Max H: You can directly use the registry manipulation functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875%28VS.85%29.aspx) if you know the changes the `.reg` file does to the registry.