# why os.environ['path'] is different from what I have in advanced>environment variables?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have been searching couple of hours for a solution but no success. I am working on a 64bit windows with python 2.7.2 32bit installation. When I run os.environ['path'] in my python this is what I get:

> 'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intergraph\Grid Analysis SDK\1.0\Program;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\'

But when I check the path in Control Panel>System>Advanced system setting>Advanced>Environment Variables" this is what I have as a value:

> C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Scripts;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\osgeo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intergraph\Grid Analysis SDK\1.0\Program;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

I am wondering why this values are different? for example C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\osgeo does not exist in os.environ['path']!! any idea?

Comment: `%SystemRoot% == C:\windows` (It gets expanded.)
About the missing paths - when were they added?

Comment: Did you restart since changing this in the Control Panel? Environment gets inherited from process to process, sometimes you can be using stalled data.

Comment: Thank you @Yirkha. Restarting the PC solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See these:

[Windows 64-bit registry v.s. 32-bit registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869783/windows-64-bit-registry-v-s-32-bit-registry)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/305097/how-to-view-the-system-registry-by-using-64-bit-versions-of-windows

os.envriron may looking in the 32 bit key which is here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node...