# Change MachineGuid C#

Tags: c#, windows

i was wondering for a project of mine, is it possible to change the MachineGuid from the registry or any other way? I've seen it in multiple applications and I can't do it myself..This is my code

```
            RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine;
            reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography");
            reg.DeleteValue("MachineGuid");
            reg.Close();

            consolebox.AppendText("MachineGuid should be changed!\n");
```

But it doesn't work.. it doesn't delete the MachineGuid value, which would automatically regenerate in about a second....

The error says that it doesnt find the value.. that MachineGuid doesn't exist... but when i go to regedit it does?

If i don't run the application as an Administrator, it says the value got deleted, but if i do it says it doesn't exist....

Comment: You said it would be re-created. Is the value different?

Comment: It would be, if the value got deleted.. It would recreate as a different value.

Comment: `Wow6432Node` masking perhaps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869783/windows-64-bit-registry-v-s-32-bit-registry ?

Comment: somebody answered my question :) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues, first you don't open the key to be writeable and you don't use the result of [`OpenSubKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx). That method returns the key you actually opened.

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine;
using(var key = reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", true)) // writeable
{
     key.DeleteValue("MachineGuid");
}
```

The `RegistryKey` object implements `IDisposable`, better apply the using pattern in that case to close and dispose the key.