# RegistryKey.OpenSubKey() returns null for a strange reason

Tags: c#, registry

Hi this is my piece of code:

```
        RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
        RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE");

        String[] str = baseKey.GetSubKeyNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(str[i]); //Testing purpose
        RegistryKey key =
                baseKey.OpenSubKey("Werewolf");
```

It prints all the subkeys due to for loop and subkeys are correct including "Werewolf" key, but `OpenSubKey("Werewolf")` returns null and I get this exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Code compiled using VS2017. Ran on both x86 and x64 machines, same error.

Comment: This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869783/windows-64-bit-registry-v-s-32-bit-registry

Comment: Thanks I saw this before posting. I use `RegistryView.Registry64` so it should be ok as subkeys are printed correctly.