# delphi reg query doesnt output value

Tags: delphi, command-line, output

I am trying to get the Value of an entry in the Registry in Delphi.
typing in `reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography /v MachineGuid` in the command line (regardless of running it as admin or not) works and outputs me the value I am looking for.
I would like Delphi to lookup that value too, but I can't get it to work.
I tried GetDosOutput (like [this one](https://delphidabbler.github.io/delphi-tips/tips/61.html)) and I tried the Component DOSCommand ([this one](https://github.com/TurboPack/DOSCommand)).
GetDosOutput and the Component DOSCommand are working very well or running other stuff (for example `systeminfo` or `getmac` or `ipconfig` or even running some batch files)
but while trying the command `reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography /v MachineGuid` using one of those methods to output the cmd content I get something like this: `ERROR: The specified registry key or value was not found.`
What works so far is this one: `reg delete  HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v MyApplication /f` and this one: `REG ADD HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /f /v BackgroundVideoUploader /t REG_SZ /d C:\temp\BackgroundVideoUploader.exe`
I assume that I am not allowed to lookup HKLM but HKCU works. But even running my Delphi App as Administrator won't enable me to prform this command getting the desired output.

Even the TRegistry Component didnt output anything (empty string):

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  try
    Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    Registry.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography', False);
    showmessage(Registry.ReadString('MachineGuid'));
  finally
    Registry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Can someone tell me why its not working and how I can get it running?

Comment: This is the wrong approach. The right approach is to use the [`TRegistry`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TRegistry) class.  It's really simple.

Comment: I tried `TRegistry` with the same result: The Value couldn't be read..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-virtualization ?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I use 32 Bit VCL App in HKLM/Software with Admin rights, so due to the content of the given link I assume Registry Virtualization should work. I just dont know how to use the flags for the `TRegistry` Component

Comment: I think you will see the expected output if you compile your app as 64-bit instead. This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/869863/282848

Comment: Thanks for the Link. I tried `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography` now, but it still doesnt output anything using the `TRegistry` Component

Comment: Ah, [here's the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/869863/282848): `Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);`. This will let your 32-bit app access the 64-bit registry.

Comment: Great, then I'll close this Q as a duplicate of the other one!